# Failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit with error: org.apache.pig.data.Typle.isNull()Z

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I am trying to store a Pig Object using CSVExcelStorage(). The Pig Script which I have used is:

```
REGISTER /usr/local/pig/lib/piggybank.jar;    
a = LOAD '/input/someText.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',');    
dump a;    
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $1,$2;    
dump b;    
STORE b into '/user/username/b_output' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage();
```

dump a gives me this result

```
(abcd,efgh,ijkl)    
(mnop,qrst,uvwx)
```

dump b gives me this result

```
(efgh,ijkl)    
(qrst,uvwx)
```

but store gives me this error

```
 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: org.apache.pig.data.Tuple.isNull()Z

 Message: Job failed! Error - # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201505250503_0003_m_000000
```

When I looked at the error by going to the JobTracker page through a browser, I found the following error

```
 Error: org.apache.pig.data.Tuple.isNull()Z
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think, you need to use `USING CSVExcelStorage(',')`. Please see the link. Please let me know if it not works for you and please provide input data. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html

Comment: @s.singh I tried `USING CSVExcelStorage(',')` but still it did not work

Comment: Can you provide your input data  for analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Code for me:

**Input:**

```
1,name1,addr2,atos
2,name2,addr2,barclays
3,name3,addr3,accenture
```

**Code:**

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar;

define CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage();

a = LOAD '/user/input/data_test3.txt' USING CSVExcelStorage(',');    
--dump a;    
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $1,$2;    
--dump b;    
STORE b into '/user/input/output' USING CSVExcelStorage();
```

**Output:**

```
name1,addr2
name2,addr2
name3,addr3
```

Comment: I checked it after downloading a new version of piggybank.jar. It worked!!!
May be there is a problem with the old piggybank.jar